# What is the relationship between Natsu and E.N.D?

Tags: fairy-tail

From what I know, E.N.D is the most powerful demon created by Zeref.
Zeref tells Natsu to choose between life and death. He's practically telling him that he'll have to decide if he wants to live or if he's going to kill himself for the sake of the other’s. He'll want to die instead of hurting his friends.

Zeref said that Igneel wanted to kill E.N.D but couldn't.

So, What is the relationship between Natsu and E.N.D?

Comment: *"Because we all know that when Natsu realizes that he’s E.N.D"* don't you answer your own question here

Comment: I don't know if it's true, I doubt he's  not E.N.D.

Comment: ahh, ok, just how that sentence was worded it seemed to imply that it was already established that E.N.D is/was Nastu

Comment: Well Zeref just told us Natsu = Etherious Natsu Dragoneel. Although it doesn't make sense to me. END's book is still there, so that means the demon isn't summoned, yet we can see Natsu. So he can't be END, yet Zeref called him END... Woot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Who will be facing me ? Is it you or END ?*" 
.

[Igneel Knows about Natsu .](http://ladymoonstache.tumblr.com/post/78321997830/end-theory-dragon-slayers-age-mysrery) He knows something but he could'nt about it.

this [article](http://ladymoonstache.tumblr.com/post/92247609213/full-natsu-dragneel-is-e-n-d-theory-more) says about Natsu where Makarov hint about Natsu's Ability .
[this](http://forums.mangafox.me/archive/index.php/t-266949-p-5.html)

That moment when Atlas meet Natsu.

E: Etherious
N: Natsu
D: Dragneel

About the [Prediction](http://www.fairytailbase.com/threads/e-n-d-and-natsus-parents.14267/)

Chapter 373 - Death or Live

> *Natsu : The Guy Igneel to wanted* 
>   Zeref : *to be precise the one he could'nt kill* .
>   Natsu : *I 'll defeat him *
>   [image: Z]
>   
>   Zeref : You can do it .However remember one thing *Igneel could'nt kill him.*
>   [image: N]
>   [image: i]
>   [image: t]
>
> *Only You and End will be able get to me .* - *Zeref*

**Fan Art of Natsu Dragneel Becoming END .**
[image: Natsu is END.]

Comment: So, what are you going to tell that E.N.D is the father of Natsu?

Comment: That was a prediction .

Comment: But rather i think that Natsu will be the one who posses the Power of END .

Comment: Based on the Article you gave to me, says that Natsu is END. END isn't his father, Therefore, natsu is a demon. According to article's : There's story behind this "                                                                                           Igneel took him with the intention of killing him but couldn’t because Natsu was just an innocent little boy. The dragon got easily attached to him. So he decided to teach Natsu how to use Dragon Slayer magic and tried to make him a good person."

Comment: Your point is ?

Comment: END isn't the  father of natsu. Therefore, natsu is a demon

Comment: But isn't obvious that Natsu is Demon-END?

Comment: Read the discussion it was stated that "Natsu is demon ." but the title of their discussion is "END and Natsu's Parents" right ? basically what I'm telling is that Majority of their discussion is all about Natsu not Parents.

Comment: " E.N.D stands for evil Natsu Dragneel" discussion

Comment: What I'm trying to say is Natsu is Demon that's all .

Comment: I have already read that articles.But why did you answer that "That was a prediction " when I ask you E.N.D is the father of Natsu? even though It wasn't told on the articles.

Comment: Maybe I just dont uderstand the question ? or wrong answer rather .

Comment: Thank you so much, for answering my questions, natsume! that would be nice topic for us.

Comment: Wrong Answer . Maybe . My answer would be like this "Yes , definitely Natsu is a Demon ."

Comment: Heh ! Dont you ... dont you .. HAHAHAH

Comment: I think this question should be updated by recent revelations as it has officially been revealed that END stands for Etherious Natsu Dragoneel in chapter 416

Comment: Well the answer should be updated and not the answer, but still you're completely right

Comment: sorry, but, what chapters are this?

Answer (score 7):

In chapter 436 it is revealed that, ...

> Natsu (Dragneel) is the younger brother of Zeref (Dragneel). Zeref's younger brother died a few years after birth. Unable to let go, Zeref researched everything he could find about bringing back the death ([R-system](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Tower_of_Heaven)), travelling through time ([Eclipse Gate](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Eclipse_Gate)) and creating magical beings ([Etherious](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Etherious)). In the end (pun not intended), he combined all of his knowledge and created an Etherious version of his younger brother, using the original body of that younger brother, named E(therious) N(atsu) D(ragneel).
>
>  [image]
>
>  On a side note. This does not yet explain why Zeref was holding the book of E.N.D. in chapter 413. By holding the book, it would give the impression that E.N.D. is not yet summoned, which imho contradicts the above.

Comment: Lets hope END's soul/powers are sealed in the book, which would explain why natsu has never transformed to END, as right now, he is not actually END, just the Shell of END.

Answer (score 3):

CH 416 blatantly told us that Natsu is E.N.D, I think the book contains Natsu's demonic powers, it would make sense, though I'm wondering why we're still discussing this. Natsu is Zerefs strongest demon

Answer (score 2):

This answer contains knowledge from different parts of the series, especially chapter 416, and up to the current chapter 421. Read it at your own risk.

> It has been revealed that Natsu, or another being inside of Natsu which may be dormant, is in fact END. It stands for Etherias Natsu Dragoneel. Crazy connection right? Though after Hiro Mashima tossed that bombshell, he sent the story into another adventure with a disbanded Fairy Tail: guild master gone missing, guild mates scattered across the continent, Natsu just returning from a two year long training by himself in the wilderness (basically pulled a Naruto) and teaming up with a semi-depressed Lucy, who was a reporter by that time, and had been keeping tabs on everyone in the hopes of the guild reforming.
>
>  The only thing I can connect Natsu and END is his Dragon Force, but even that's far-fetched since the other Dragon Slayers can also enter Dragon Force. However, from what we have seen so far, none of the other Dragon Slayers have been able to stomach other Dragon Slayers' powers and combine them with their own, except for Natsu, which is where his END part comes in. That's the only connection that I can come up with so far. Gajeel had done it too, so maybe he has something to do with Zeref's demons as well. It would make sense why there are the three dragons that talk together, about the three dragonslayers meeting and them forging their own path from now on.
>
>  That and when the series first starts jogging in the "Erza Arc", we can see Natsu ate a rock of Etherias (hint hint) which should have killed him (hint hint) but it didn't. Instead, it just gave him a power up and a massive stomachache (hint hint) in the fight against Jellal who was possessed by a demon of Zeref. The story is now at chapter 421, and those stuffs in the first, second and third arcs are starting to make sense. But as there have been a plethora of arcs since then, you kinda need to go back and re-read it.

Anyway, this is just based off of my observations and what I have connected. If you'd like the refute my findings and opinions in a mature rebuttal you may.

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 416 pretty much confirmed that Natsu is E.N.D, but there is always the chance that E.N.D is some sort of clone of Natsu and Zeref was calling the clone Natsu (I'm just looking on the bright side...). Although the guild is now disbanded (Assuming they don't start it up again) I PERSONALLY believe that the ex-guild members can save Natsu.

Answer (score -1):

Well as far as we know, Natsu is Zeref's brother revived with a forbidden curse. I think that we can say that inside Natsu there is something he is not aware of. No matter how badly he is beaten up, he doesn't die and his body stays intact, which shows that he is most likely indeed a demon.

I think Natsu is unaware because E.N.D. (the book) hasn't opened yet and so the etherious power inside Natsu is present and protects him while he himself doesn't have to do a thing. Also I think that as soon as E.N.D. awakens he will take over Natsu's body, and I think that was what Zeref meant by "Will it be you or E.N.D. who kills me?"  So when E.N.D. awakens and takes over Nastu, Natsu could defeat him with his willpower or he could succumb to him, which would probably mean the end of the world they know and the death of all of Natsu's guildmates by his own hands or something.

This is just a guess though.

Comment: I made some edits for grammar. I don't follow Fairy Tail, so if I've somehow changed the meaning of something, feel free to make adjustments back to what you intended.